# jquery, .change() method, показывает неправильное value

Tags: jquery, методы

Я использую данный код

```
jQuery("#autocomplete").change(function() {
    var valueAutocomlete = jQuery( "#autocomplete" ).val();
    console.log(valueAutocomlete);
});
```

Я подключил google api адресов в поле, всё работает супер, но когда пользователь выбирает данную из выпадающего списка адресов, который предлагает гугл, мне не отображает её в переменно `valueAutocomlete`

Как мне получать правильно value? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: настроить обработку события [`select`](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select) у плагина?

Comment: @teran тут, я так понял, речь про autocomplete из google maps api, а не jquery autocomplete)

Comment: @ВадимЛешкевич действительно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

использовать слушатель события `place_changed` из google maps api

```js
function initAutocomplete() {
  
  var field = document.getElementById('autocomplete');
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(field);

  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', () => {
    console.log(autocomplete.getPlace()); //вернет объект с информацией о месте
    console.log(field.value); //ну или просто значение поля
  });

}
```

```html
<input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" type="text" />
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
```